# Can one way hash functions be used to sanitize DB queries?

Tags: security

Since the primary goal while sanitizing inputs is to treat them as strings rather than as code for DBMS languages, this would get rid of the syntax. Applying the hash on the db entries as well would let us query it.

Comment: just use parameters man, it's not hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashing queries and data would function for equality tests, but nothing else: hashing doesn't preserve order or similarity; substring and range queries, for example, would be impossible.

Any reasonable DB interface allows parameterized queries which are safe against injection attacks, and which do not limit the expressivity of the queries.